# I am a Malaysian. Can i travel to other countries besides Schengen while my Poland TRC is in progress?

Tags: visas, poland, residency, malaysian-citizens

I am a Malaysian. Can i travel to other countries besides Schengen while my Poland TRC is in progress?

I am planning to go for a vacation in India in November this year, which is this time the Poland TRC application will be in progress.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid visa (with enough days) to travel back to Poland afterwards. Decision alone is not a permit to enter Schengen zone.

Comment: I don't understand your answer's second sentence. Do you mean that an _application_ alone is not a permit to enter the Schengen zone?

Comment: No I mean a _decision_ alone. https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Ii5pMe8MgNE/WdVAetfg3nI/AAAAAAAABUM/XroY3GQ-34Uy3qKbvmCB6z7QrzKxFc75ACLcBGAs/s1600/DecyzjaOdmownaDziecko1_Resized1.jpg

Comment: Ah. You mean a valid Polish TRC is, by itself, insufficient to enter the Schengen area.

Comment: It definitely is, but TS says his one is still processed. You can travel once you have the actual plastic card at hand, a confirmation of a positive decision alone (as in a photo I've posted link to) is not a travel document, once you've received it you still should wait a few months for the actual TRC without leaving Poland.